# The image for the "How do I view vote counts?" part of the "Established-user" privilege is outdated

Tags: bug, design, help-center, privileges

The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) > [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) > [Established user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) page currently looks like this:

> [image: Screenshot showing the awful vote up/vote down buttons]

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yi9X8.png) shows the vote up/vote down buttons from before a redesign - the image should really be changed to look something like one of the following<sup>1,2,3</sup>:

> [image: Sample new image 1. Use this one if you want - I don't mind.]

or

> [image: Sample new image 2. Use this one if you want - I don't mind.]

to avoid the inconsistency.

---

<sup>1</sup> I wanted to find a post which had 24 upvotes and 11 downvotes for consistency, but couldn't (easily) and couldn't be bothered to construct a query on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) to find an exact match. Not that the actual numbers particularly matter.

<sup>2</sup> I don't think the blue radial lines are necessary to point out that a click needs to happen: the mouse cursor is already shown, and the text above it already says (emphasis mine): "*You can view the vote counts by **clicking** on the score of a post.*"

<sup>3</sup> I have no problem if, to save extra time and effort, Stack Overflow wants to just use one of the images that I created. For that reason, I've not added the obligatory [red freehand circle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/284827) around the vote up/vote down buttons.

Comment: these old vote button looks like they were coming from arqade.se .. interesting :D.

Comment: @Tom yeah, the screenshot of the "old" buttons was not taken on SO.

Comment: MSE duplicate from May 2015: [Expanded Usercard, See Vote Counts help page needs an overhaul](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256482/expanded-usercard-see-vote-counts-help-page-needs-an-overhaul)

Comment: I knew everything related to Css or consitency in display is a dupe as Nothing can escape our OCD..

Comment: So, I've seen this before on meta questions; is this a feature-request or a bug? It's got both tags, so I don't know if I should vote based on agreement with the request, or on its quality as a bug report... :)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - If it helps, I've removed the [tag:feature-request] tag as it's more of a bug than a feature request.

Comment: @Stijn - somehow your second comment slipped my attention. Thanks for finding that - I didn't find that when I searched for potential duplicates.

Comment: *”I don't think the blue radial lines are necessary to point out that a click needs to happen”* Clearly the solution is an animated GIF with exploding starbursts. You don’t actually expect anyone to *read*, do you?

Comment: Another SO page with outdated vote arrows - any tag synonyms page.

Comment: @CodyGray - Okay - I made an animated version. No additional reading required!