# Update images in Stack Overflow's help centre

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center, privileges

I recently saw all the privileges I have earned/can earn.

Some pages of them, contain outdated images. Can we update them?

Especially:

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki the image:

> [image: community wiki]

can be replaced with:

> [image: community wiki new]

---

---

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes the image:

> [image]

can be replaced with:

> [image: new, show exampes better please!]

*(the above is not so good, so, if you can suggest anything, please do it!)*

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user the image:

> [image: expanded & not]

can be replaced with:

> [image: new expanded & not]

From https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions the image:

> [image: close in Meta]

can be replaced with the meta close dialog:

> [image: close in meta new]

and the Stack Overflow one:

> [image: stackoverflow close dialog]

As I don't have the privilege to access site's analytics, can you say if images [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) are outdated?

Feel free to edit this question to add own examples and let me know where you disagree.

The question has been inspired from [The image for the "How do I view vote counts?" part of the "Established-user" privilege is outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380760), so I haven't included the images there.

Comment: I'd rather just remove the images than have to keep updating them every time they change.

Comment: @animuson or have actual HTML examples such that when the system is updated, the examples will be updated with it.

Comment: *”I couldn’t recognize them when I joined Stack Overflow.”* Seriously? Yes, the design on the live site has changed slightly, but new fonts and colorless icons kept you from recognizing what these Help Center articles were referring to? That strains credibility.

Comment: @double-beep Please include the information in your last comment, and anything else offering a reason why it's beneficial to update these, in your question. Right now, your question just sounds like you happened to notice they were out of date and "wouldn't it be nice" to have them updated. Updating them takes time and effort for someone. Why should that time be spent on this task? At least to me, and other people too, based on the above comments, the current images are sufficient to communicate, even if they're a bit out of date. If they are causing confusion, that's important to know.

Comment: You thought that the colored icons were only given to high-rep people? I wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like most of these were "fixed" but removing images altogether. I updated the screenshot for the expanded usercard, however.

Thanks!