# Update Privileges Documentation Images

Tags: feature-request, help-center

Currently, there is an image that shows an outdated image of Stack Overflow on the *[Help center > Privileges > reduce ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads)* page.

It is an outdated image and could be replaced with a more streamlined, clean image although this could be a lot of work for just the help center.

There are also other places where this occurs. An example is the [set bounties privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). It is an old ui but more importantly, it **does not show** the more vital part, **where the set bounty button is!** This ***begs*** for redo.

There is a similar question here: *[Update images in Stack Overflow's help centre](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380801/update-images-in-stack-overflows-help-centre)*. But it doesn’t mention any of these pages.

[image: Outdated image of Stack Overflow]

Comment: Personally, I think we don't need this image at all. The name of "Reduce Ads" explains all.

Comment: Ok, thing is, i went to the page because i was seeing ads and thought i got something to do with reduced/no ads. i was seeing sidebar ads. So i went there to see which ads were removed. Of course this image is fine but the image on https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties is worse. It is an old ui but more importantly, it does not show the more important part, where the set bounty button is! This begs for redo more than this one.

Comment: [Honestly, no one really reads the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367899/new-staff-and-mod-labels-on-site-metas-and-meta-stack-exchange/367925#comment1229056_367925) so I don't think it'd be missed if the image were outright deleted...